# MacPro 1st Gen - can it handle SSDs?

Tags: ssd, mac-pro

I have a MacPro 1,1 and am considering putting an SSD in it to give it a boost. Can I safely assume compatibility or will its ancient  hardware and architecture cause issues? It cannot, as I recently discovered, run Mountain Lion so I'm not sure if I should even try bringing it up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm that I have installed an SSD into my Mac Pro 1,1. Because the drive is a 2.5" drive, though, I am using a 2.5" to 3.5" SATA converter sled. Note, if I recall, there are some of these converters that only work with certain models.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely confirm the claim that you can use an adapter before you go out and buy SSD drives.  I have a MacPro 3,1 with the Apple RAID controller.  I was told by a couple vendors specializing in hardware upgrades for Macs that the adapters being sold now fit the current production Mac Pros, but not the 3,1.  Yours is even older.  There have been some changes to the drive carriers.

I'd very much like to hear of any source for an adapter that will definitely work the the 3,1 or earlier models.

Answer (score 1):

Ia m using a Quad 3.0 Ghz MacPro with an SSD from OWC. They have an adapter that connects the SSD to the original sled and works great. I created a boot disk with Mac OSX 10.7.5 Lion and then used Carbon Copy Cloner to move all the data from my old boot drive. Boots in about 8-10 seconds and runs Photoshop faster than the 8 core brand new MacPro my friend has. I also bought a replacement sled which is only supposed to work in the 8 core machine. It works fine but you can't put the side cover back on the tower because it sticks about an inch to inch and half further. I still use it when I want to replace an old drive or format a new one. And I can keep an off line data drive to swap in an emergency.